# vagrant up fails for bento/ubuntu-16.04 on Oracle VirtualBox 5.0.16 r105871

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, bento

Today I was planning to get the latest Ubuntu release into my virtual box using vagrant. After loading the image and running `vagrant up`, I got an error as reported below, which relates to the network configuration of the virtual box.

Interestingly, there are already some posts online (mainly on GitHub, e.g.: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7155), but also on AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/760871/network-settings-fail-for-ubuntu-xenial64-vagrant-box), StackOverflow ([vagrant up command giving error and eth1 not showing a resolvable ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003153/vagrant-up-command-giving-error-and-eth1-not-showing-a-resolvable-ip-address)) and StackExchange (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188413/not-able-to-resolve-ip-address-for-eth1-in-vagrant-vm). However these issues relate to either `xenial64` (i.e. **not** `bento`) or use a `public_network` configuration.

As reported in https://askubuntu.com/questions/760871/network-settings-fail-for-ubuntu-xenial64-vagrant-box, this issue does not exist for `ubuntu/trusty64` or `ubuntu/wily64`, but seems to be an issue for both `ubuntu/xenial64` and `bento/ubuntu-16.04` (i.e. both Ubuntu 16 boxes).

As you will see in my `Vagrantfile` below, I have a simple setup for `bento/ubuntu-16.04` and use `private_network` only. To be clear, I can't really use this post ([vagrant up command giving error and eth1 not showing a resolvable ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003153/vagrant-up-command-giving-error-and-eth1-not-showing-a-resolvable-ip-address)) since it suggests to comment out the `public_network` part of the vagrant configuration. Also, I should mention that there are no other VM's running at the time this error occurs.

From the error log it seems obvious that there is an issue with the netowrk interface `eth1`, but what exactly the problem is, is unclear to me. I have previously successfully started the `hashicorp/precise32` and `ubuntu/trusty64` Ubuntu boxes with the same vagrant configuration and the same Oracle VB and have not encountered this problem.

Any help is appreciated. My technical setup and reference files are listed below.

Cheers
AHL

---

Setup:

- Vagrant: v1.8.1
- Oracle VirtualBox: v5.0.16 r105871
- Ubuntu box: bento/ubuntu-16.04 (https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04)
- Host machine: Lenovo X1 Carbon, Windows 10

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

end
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\AHL\workspace>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 5.0.16 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

C:\Users\AHL\workspace>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your list, you need to add https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6871

The issue is still open - There are some users who reported they could fix the issue (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6871#issuecomment-223290622 or https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6871#issuecomment-222348226)

If you can build your box yourself using packer, there are some fixes on the network issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the problem and found that for some reason, the virtual box did not connect the virtual cable to the network interface.

I solved it by adding

```
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
```

to my `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|` loop, for example in my case I wanted 1GB RAM, USB3 and the network cable connected:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbxhci", "on"]               # Connect USB3 disk
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
end
```

I did not need this `--cableconnected1` line in any other boxes I have used, only in `config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"`.

Maybe you have to check if doing `vagrant up`does not connect any of your cables, I had also an extra network and `eth0` was unwired and `eth1` was wired.

Check your particular case. Maybe you have to play with the number after the option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, this fix saved the day. Just adding the `--cableconnected1` line worked for me